# Is nexus-staging-maven-plugin needed if using maven-release-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to configure Maven for deployment to the central repository.

I've been primarily using the following documentation:

- http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html
- http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html

The configuration they guide you through uses the nexus-staging-maven-plugin for deployment, which they say is the recommended way to do it:

> The Nexus Staging Maven Plugin is the recommended way to deploy your
>   components to OSSRH and release them to the Central Repository.

In the same documentation they show you how to deploy using the maven-release-plugin. According to the maven-release-plugin documentation, it can perform direct deployments and staging deployments, which seems to overlap the nexus-staging-maven-plugin's job.

I would prefer to use the maven-release-plugin because I like the way it automates the process of updating versions and creating release branches.

The documentation doesn't specifically say to remove the nexus-staging-maven-plugin when using the maven-release-plugin.

If you use the maven-release-plugin, do you need the nexus-staging-maven-plugin? Do they work together in any way, or does the nexus-staging-maven-plugin do something the maven-release-plugin does not do?

Thank you

Comment: The maven-release-plugin is intended for the release process for Maven...and of course will deploy artifacts to the defined remote repository...which in case of Maven central is a staging repository...whereas the nexus-staging-repository will deploy the artifacts to the repository where you can automatically close the staging repository which in case of the maven-release-plugin you have to do manually....

Comment: @khmarbaise I think what I was missing is the fact that the maven-release-plugin is simply calling the configured deploy plugin, which is by default the maven deploy plugin. Using nexus-staging replaces the default deploy plugin and is called by maven-release when you perform the release. So they can be used together.